# Reading JSON from URL and passing username and password

Tags: c#, json, httpclient, winrt-xaml

I am using WinRT framework. I have to get JSON response from service URL by passing username and password.

Here is the code I have tried

```
var credentials = new NetworkCredential("***", "***");
        var handler = new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = credentials };
        //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("UserID", "****");
        //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Password", "****");
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
```

But this throw error

Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server Error).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The service you are calling is encountering an error internally. We have no idea why, and can't help you without any further details. Is this service yours? If it is, debug it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Service is running fine when I try to use the service in any browser. It asks for username and password and then it displays me the JSON response.

Comment: What type of authentication is the service using?

Comment: https://mobility.gap.com/MobileAppProvider/resources/gapresources/v1/buildings

Comment: can you see the url and figure out what kind of authentication is this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing you miss is `User-Agent`. This works....

```
var credentials = new NetworkCredential("****", "*****");
var handler = new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = credentials, AllowAutoRedirect = true };

HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; de; rv:1.9.2.12) Gecko/20101026 Firefox/3.6.12"); 
var responseString = await client.GetStringAsync("https://mobility.gap.com/MobileAppProvider/resources/gapresources/v1/buildings");
```

Comment: Thanks my friend this has saved my whole day. Appreciate your help here